# on radio click not working with checkboxes with same ids

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox like so:

```html
<div class="steps-row-first">
<div class="radio-wrapper">
              <div class="radio-group">
                <input type="radio" id="anotherCheese" name="anotherCheese" value="yes" />
                <label>Yes</label>
              </div>
              <div class="radio-group">
                <input type="radio" name="anotherCheese" value="no" />
                <label>No</label>
              </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

And I am using jQuery to append to steps-row-first when someone clicks Yes:

```
$('#anotherCheese').on("click", function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'yes')
    {
      $(".steps-row-first").append('<div class="radio-wrapper"> <div class="radio-group"> <input type="radio" id="anotherCheese" name="anotherCheese" value="yes"/> <label>Yes</label> </div><div class="radio-group"> <input type="radio" name="anotherCheese" value="no"/> <label>No</label> </div></div>');
    }
  });
```

This creates another radio button with the same id anotherCheese, but when I click Yes on the second set of radio buttons, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: IDs must be unique, the selector only matches the first one. Use a class instead.

Comment: It is invalid to have to elements with the same id. Use classes to target those elements.

Comment: I tried with a class and it only works once.